# How to use a comma in lstlisting keywords?

Tags: listings

I am creating a language for the *doxygen* tool. I need to create a set of new keywords. When I try to use the comma in one of them, it does not highlighting. I protect comma with a backslash, but it seems to be useless.

Does anyone know how I can use comma in new keywords ?

Here is what I have tried.

```
\lstdefinelanguage{doxygen}%
{
    alsoletter={\\,[,],/,*,\,},%
    morekeywords=[2]{/**,*/,///,\\brief,\\author,\\date,%
                     \\return,\\param[in,out],\\param[in],\\param[out],%
                     \\pre,\\post},%
    otherkeywords={},%
    morestring=[b]"
}
```

The problem is with the `\param[in,out]` keyword.

**[EDIT]**
Here is a minimal example

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{doxygen}%
{
    alsoletter={\\,[,],/,*,\,},%
    morekeywords=[2]{/**,*/,\\brief,%
                     \\return,\\param[in,out],\\param[in],\\param[out]}
}

\lstdefinestyle{basic}{
    basicstyle={\small \ttfamily},
    keywordstyle={\bfseries\color{black}},
    linewidth={\textwidth}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=doxygen,style=basic]
/** 
  \brief compute the gcd 

  \param[in] n the first number
  \param[in,out] m the second number and 
                   and gcd after the function returns
  \return terminaison code
 */
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is not that you want `\param[in,out]` — and also `\param[in]` and `\param[out]` — to be keywords; the problem is that you would like arguments in square brackets to be typeset in the same way that a keyword would. You can do this by defining a special kind of "comment" (really, just a span of characters) which is delimited by `[` and `]`, and which is typeset as a keyword would be.

Using your same pre-amble and example:

```
\newcommand\keywordstyle{\bfseries\color{black}}

\lstdefinelanguage{doxygen}{
  alsoletter={\\,/,*},
  morekeywords=[2]{/**,*/,\\brief,\\return,\\param},
  morecomment=[n][\keywordstyle]{[}{]}
}

\lstdefinestyle{basic}{
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    keywordstyle={\keywordstyle},
    linewidth={\textwidth}
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Listing with hilighting]

As I have defined the style for `[...]` blocks, it will correctly highlight nested pairs of brackets — wherever they occur, which may or may not be what you want for doxygen (which I am not familiar with).

Comment: That's really brilliant ! I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: Someone should accept the answer...and I don't get how the comments are made here? There is no comment symbol e. g. for "compute the god". How is it made?

Comment: @manuel.kuehner: looks like Benoit has come back to accept it. I'm not sure what you mean by "a comment symbol" for `compute the gcd`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Niel: Hello! For example `\param[in,out] m the second number and`. The `m the second number and` part is a comment, right? How is a comment marked? How does `listings` know that this is a comment here? In other languages there a spefific comment symbols like `%` or `#` or `/*`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to redefine the way `,` is treated by [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) through the experimental *literate programming* feature. This uses the `literate[*]<replacement>...<replacement>` macro.

```
\lstdefinelanguage{doxygen}%
{
    alsoletter={\\,/,*,[,]},%
    morekeywords=[2]{/**,*/,\\brief,%
                     \\return,,\\param[in,out],\\param[in],\\param[out]},
    literate=*{|}{,}{1}
}
```

The above does *not* define `,` to be `alsoletter`. However, `literate=*{|}{,}{1}` replaces the occurrence of `|` to `,` of width `1`. Note the star `*`, as suggestion by the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf):

> The optional star indicates that literate replacements should not be
>   made in strings, comments, and other delimited text

After the replacement, `\param[in|out]` becomes `\param[in,out]`, which is recognized as a keyword in `\morekeywords[2]{...,\\param[in,out],...}`.

Your code segment now has this form:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=doxygen,style=basic]
/** 
  \brief compute the gcd 

  \param[in] n the first number
  \param[in|out] m the second number and 
                   and gcd after the function returns
  \return termination code
 */
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image: Literate programming in listings]

An easy way out would have been to merely use `;` instead of `,` (adding it to `alsoletter` or `alsodigit`, of course).

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I would greatly have prefer to do not change the comma. The problem takes place in the slides of one of my course. Therefore, it is a little annoying to modify each listing before putting it in beamer. The `\param[in,out]` is a _doxygen_ command. However, if I need to, I will. Thanks again.
Does your answer mean that the comma cannot be "captured" ?

Comment: @Benoit: I'm not sure, but that could be the case. Not sure how `listings` parses a comma-separated lists...