# Other keywords and symbols highlighting with lstlisting

Tags: listings

Trying to make my own style of C++ listings I met the problem.

First of all I decide to highlight semicolons. I read in docs

> otherkeywords is designed to define keywords like =>, ->, -->, --, ::,
>   and so on.

Fine, that is what I need:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{main-color}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.7176, 0.7764}
\definecolor{back-color}{rgb}{0.1686, 0.1686, 0.1686}
\definecolor{string-color}{rgb}{0.3333, 0.5254, 0.345}
\definecolor{key-color}{rgb}{0.8, 0.47, 0.196}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily \color{main-color}},
    backgroundcolor = {\color{back-color}},
    stringstyle = {\color{string-color}},
    otherkeywords = {;},
    keywordstyle = {\color{key-color}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style = mystyle]
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x = 2;

//comment
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    cout << "stand_alone_complex" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

It works pretty well. Then I want to highlight << and >> with another color. Changed part of example is here:

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily \color{main-color}},
    backgroundcolor = {\color{back-color}},
    stringstyle = {\color{string-color}},
    otherkeywords = {;},
    keywordstyle = {\color{key-color}},
    classoffset = 1,
    otherkeywords = {<<, >>},
    morekeywords = {<<, >>},
    keywordstyle = {\color{yellow}},
    classoffset = 0,
}
```

If I keep only `otherkeywords = {<<, >>},` it would highlight "<<",">>" by key-color, not yellow. If I keep only `morekeywords = {<<, >>},`, it wouldn't work. So I keep both of them like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/using-different-colors-for-different-keywords-in-lstlisting) and it works, but semicolons are not highlighted anymore.
Seems like the last `otherkeyword` is only valid. 
If I use code below, nothing highlights.

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily \color{main-color}},
    backgroundcolor = {\color{back-color}},
    stringstyle = {\color{string-color}},
    otherkeywords = {;},
    keywordstyle = {\color{key-color}},
    keywordstyle = [2]{\color{blue}},
    morekeywords = [2]{<<, >>},
    % or otherkeywords = [2]{<<, >>},
    % or both 
}
```

How does it work? How can I highlight two different symbols in two different colors?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As far as I can recall, the *correct* way is to claim all `otherkeywords` you need at once and then classify them in different `morekeywords=[i]`.

(To be more precise, `otherkeywords` does not support `[i]`-syntax. Also it will erase old list on the second call, as you just observed.)

(*correct* is in italic because the manual does not mention this sort of usage. It might fail in the future version.)

The following will work

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily \color{main-color}},
    backgroundcolor = {\color{back-color}},
    stringstyle = {\color{string-color}},
    keywordstyle = {\color{key-color}},
    keywordstyle = [2]{\color{lime}},
    keywordstyle = [3]{\color{yellow}},
    keywordstyle = [4]{\color{teal}},
    otherkeywords = {;,<<,>>,++},
    morekeywords = [2]{;},
    morekeywords = [3]{<<, >>},
    morekeywords = [4]{++},
}
```

[image]

---

The full code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{main-color}{rgb}{0.6627, 0.7176, 0.7764}
\definecolor{back-color}{rgb}{0.1686, 0.1686, 0.1686}
\definecolor{string-color}{rgb}{0.3333, 0.5254, 0.345}
\definecolor{key-color}{rgb}{0.8, 0.47, 0.196}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily \color{main-color}},
    backgroundcolor = {\color{back-color}},
    stringstyle = {\color{string-color}},
    keywordstyle = {\color{key-color}},
    keywordstyle = [2]{\color{lime}},
    keywordstyle = [3]{\color{yellow}},
    keywordstyle = [4]{\color{teal}},
    otherkeywords = {;,<<,>>,++},
    morekeywords = [2]{;},
    morekeywords = [3]{<<, >>},
    morekeywords = [4]{++},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style = mystyle]
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x = 2;

//comment
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    cout << "stand_alone_complex" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```