# Personalize keywords in listings

Tags: color, listings, r

In a report, I present a new R package and I want to color the new functions and not the "base" ones. However, I want to keep the strings, comment color and also `for` and `if`.

I find several similar questions and [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327076/other-keywords-and-symbols-highlighting-with-lstlisting) with the code I want but that doesn't work...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{beaver}{rgb}{0.62, 0.51, 0.44}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{beaver},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  keywordstyle=\color{black},
  keywordstyle = [2]{\color{blue}},
  keywordstyle = [3]{\color{red}},
  otherkeywords = {fastqPairedFilter, for, if},
  morekeywords = [2]{fastqPairedFilter},
  morekeywords = [3]{for, if},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
#### Trim and Filter

if(!file_test("-d", filt_path)){
  dir.create(filt_path, recursive = TRUE)
  }

for(i in seq_along(fnFs)){
  fastqPairedFilter(c(fnFs[[i]], fnRs[[i]]),
                    c(filtFs[[i]], filtRs[[i]]),
                    trimLeft = 0, truncLen = 0,
                    maxN = 0, maxEE = c(2, 5), truncQ = 2,
                    compress=TRUE)
  }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is a little trick because I color the "base" keywords in black. (Note that `blue` and `red` are already defined)

Here's the output:
[image]

Actually, I don't know if I can overwrite `for` and `if` because they're still in the "base" keywords. But at least, this should work for `fastqPairedFilter`, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `deletekeywords` for the keywords you want to change (`for` and `if`) and define a style (I've called it `Rlst`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{beaver}{rgb}{0.62, 0.51, 0.44}

\lstdefinestyle{Rlst}{ 
    language=R,               
    frame=tb,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{beaver},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    keywordstyle = [2]{\color{blue}},
    keywordstyle = [3]{\color{red}},
    deletekeywords = {for, if},
    morekeywords = [2]{fastqPairedFilter},
    morekeywords = [3]{for, if},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}[style=Rlst]
    #### Trim and Filter

    if(!file_test("-d", filt_path)){
      dir.create(filt_path, recursive = TRUE)
      }

    for(i in seq_along(fnFs)){
      fastqPairedFilter(c(fnFs[[i]], fnRs[[i]]),
                      c(filtFs[[i]], filtRs[[i]]),
                      trimLeft = 0, truncLen = 0,
                      maxN = 0, maxEE = c(2, 5), truncQ = 2,
                      compress=TRUE)
      }
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MrSnake You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!