# Flatfile comma and semicolon hightlight in lstlisting?

Tags: listings

How do I create a lstlisting language handling Comman and Semicolon separated list.

Would like to highlight the keywords "STOP, START, ATTEMPT" as well as ", , :" (actual comma and semicolon)

My attempt so far

```
\definecolor{eclipseBlue}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{eclipseGreen}{RGB}{63,127,95}
\definecolor{eclipsePurple}{RGB}{127,0,85}

\lstdefinelanguage{flatfile}{
  morekeywords={STOP, START, ATTEMPT, INTERMEDIATE},
  morekeywords=[2]{\,}, % Actual comma
  morekeywords=[3]{:},
  sensitive=false,
}

\lstset{
    language={flatfile},
    [..]                  
    keywordstyle=\color{eclipsePurple},
    keywordstyle =[2]\color{eclipseGreen},
    keywordstyle =[3]\color{eclipseBlue},
}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Partial CDR STOP Record}]
STOP,YF08,0x00015F3800000002,1919632,GMT+05:30-Calcutta,04/12/2019,09:57:21.7,0,67,73,04/12/2019,09:57:32.5,2,1006,16,VoIP,IP-TO-IP,DEFAULT,,22223333,44445555,,0,,0,,0,22223333,EGRESS_RL,1,YF08:EGRESS_TG,[..]
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25257/47927

Comment: Yeah, tried to apply that however, I couldn't get it to work. But thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be quite tricky and got me a bit confused, because commas, colons and the regular keywords all seemingly need to be treated very differently.

Firstly, comma and colon need to be defined using `otherkeywords` because they are not letters. However, it is not possible to assign a specific color to them when using `otherkeywords`. Furthermore, it seems that you can define `otherkeywords` only if `morekeywords` is called without optional parameter. Maybe I am wrong, but this is what I found. Therefore, I decided to make `eclipseGreen` the default color for keywords which is then also applied to the strings defined in `otherkeywords`.

Secondly, I applied `eclipsePurple` to the regular keywords.

Finally, I defined the colon once again with `morekeywords` and the third color, which amazingly worked (see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283543/47927)). This seems to be, however, only possible, if the colon is previously defined by `otherkeywords`. This trick again did not work for the comma though.

Maybe someone else can explain what's going on. Anyways, the regular keywords are now purple, commas are green and colons are blue, which is, hopefully, what you wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}
\definecolor{eclipseBlue}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{eclipseGreen}{RGB}{63,127,95}
\definecolor{eclipsePurple}{RGB}{127,0,85}

\lstdefinelanguage{flatfile}{
  morekeywords={},
  otherkeywords={{,},:},
  morekeywords=[2]{STOP,START,ATTEMPT,INTERMEDIATE},
  morekeywords=[3]{:},
  sensitive=false,
}

\lstset{
    language={flatfile},
    keywordstyle=\color{eclipseGreen},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{eclipsePurple},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{eclipseBlue},
    breaklines
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Partial CDR STOP Record}]
STOP,YF08,0x00015F3800000002,1919632,GMT+05:30-Calcutta,04/12/2019,09:57:21.7,0,67,73,04/12/2019,09:57:32.5,2,1006,16,VoIP,IP-TO-IP,DEFAULT,,22223333,44445555,,0,,0,,0,22223333,EGRESS_RL,1,YF08:EGRESS_TG
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out in such detail. Seems to be some weird quirks here for sure. Cheers