# Code snippet highlighting for .arff files (WEKA tool)

Tags: code

I would like to know how to go about getting [syntax highlighting for WEKA files](https://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+Syntax+Highlighting).  This is a tool used for analyzing large data.

In notepad++ this is an example of how the arff file shows up with the [syntax highlighting](https://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+Syntax+Highlighting):

[image]

I started with the [code found here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_listing) and was modifying it, but so far have not gotten the desired result.  Here is what I have started so far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=WEKA Code]
% Assignment for BIG DATA - FIT DATA
% Author: I AM
% email: email@email.com
% 9 attributes
% 188 instances

@relation FIT

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators
@attribute TOTOPANDS real % Total number of operands
@attribute VG real        % McCabe's cyclomatic complexity
@attribute NLOGIC real    % Number of logical operators
@attribute LOC real       % Lines of code
@attribute ELOC real      % Executable line of code
@attribute FAULTS real    % Number of faults

@data
22,85,203,174,9,0,362,40,0
21,87,186,165,5,0,379,32,0
30,107,405,306,25,0,756,99,0
6,5,19,6,2,0,160,9,0
21,47,168,148,7,0,352,29,0
28,38,161,114,10,3,375,40,0
27,218,1522,1328,114,0,1026,310,0
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `language=Python` is overriding your style.  Either specify your style after the `language` option, or drop that option, or place both options in `\lstset` in the appropriate order.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, can you help me get started?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start.  Drop the `language=Python`, it has nothing to do with the syntax of what you are highlighting.  Now you need to define your comment style with

```
comment=[l]{\%},
```

saying that rest of the line after a `%` is a comment, and set-up keywords in two different categories:

```
keywords={@relation,@attribute,@data},
morekeywords=[2]{real,integer,numeric,string,date},
```

so you can highlight them with different colours.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle={[2]\color{magenta}},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    comment=[l]{\%},
    keywords={@relation,@attribute,@data},
    morekeywords=[2]{real,integer,numeric,string,date},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,caption=WEKA Code]
% Assignment for BIG DATA - FIT DATA
% Author: I AM
% email: email@email.com
% 9 attributes
% 188 instances

@relation FIT

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators
@attribute TOTOPANDS real % Total number of operands
@attribute VG real        % McCabe's cyclomatic complexity
@attribute NLOGIC real    % Number of logical operators
@attribute LOC real       % Lines of code
@attribute ELOC real      % Executable line of code
@attribute FAULTS real    % Number of faults

@data
22,85,203,174,9,0,362,40,0
21,87,186,165,5,0,379,32,0
30,107,405,306,25,0,756,99,0
6,5,19,6,2,0,160,9,0
21,47,168,148,7,0,352,29,0
28,38,161,114,10,3,375,40,0
27,218,1522,1328,114,0,1026,310,0
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This covers everything in your example.  It does not colour the commas in the data, but that may not be possible with `listings`, cf. [How to use a comma in lstlisting keywords?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25257/15925)